# Is it wise to manually synchronize database operations and avoiding the inbuilt database synchronization mechanism?

Tags: database, synchronization

I am making this application which reads and writes from a database and is accessed by multiple users. To avoid concurrency issues I am using mutex. The database that I am using is postgresql. Its documentation says it is ACID compliant and provides various levels of synchronization such as read_committed etc. So I can avoid using mutex and put all my statements in a transaction block and the database will take care of it. But I am not fully confident of using this transaction based approach as I am having trust issues with the database automatic mechanism.

My current approach:

```
mutex.lock();
\\perform database operations
mutex.unlock();
```

Alternative approach:

```
begin transaction
\\perform database operations
end transaction
```

Is it wise to handle with mutex or should I rely on the database mechanism.
Each user is accessing the database in a separate thread. And database operations are simple. One read and one write. That is all.

Comment: Mutex is application level, not database level. It does not guarantee valid DB atomicity between _multiple DB statements_ in multiple processes (or if not used consistently). Utilize _DB transactions_ as required for valid operations. RDBMS locks and escalations are well-developed. Applications can also perform own locking and guards; it should be as a secondary nature, not to replace proper DB usages.

Comment: Atomicity I am taking care through try and catch statements.

Comment: Read again for basic limitation of mutex and why DB-level transactions cannot be replaced with such.

Comment: (But hey, do what you want. Don’t bother listening to advice, after solicitation, of people who write this sort of code everyday in complex environments.. many of us have overcome any “trust issues” with relational databases after curating understanding.)

Answer (score 1):

If the database is being accessed by multiple users simultaneously, an application level mutex does absolutely nothing to prevent them from stepping on each other on the database side<sup>1</sup>. You must use the locking constructs provided at the database level (transactions) to achieve what you are after.

A better use case for the application level mutex is to provide resource locking between threads running within the application (which may also be achievable with database transactions, but use the right tool for the job).

---

<sub>1: I have to be careful here: if an application handles multiple users in a single instance, or otherwise shares database objects outside of the database, then a mutex might be a good way to do locking. Even then, it won't protect things *on the database* (meaning it's not functionality that is built into the DBMS), and it's still probably better to let the database take care of it's own locks.</sub>

Comment: Since I am using mutex how multiple users would access simultaneously? Access to the database is through the application(JDBC code).

Comment: are multiple users all accessing the database through a single instance of the application? That is the only case where the mutex would help, but even there you might be better off letting the database handle it's own locking instead of trying to recreate it in the application.

Comment: Believe it or not, many applications run with many processes (and or servers / containers) or otherwise share common database artifacts even if they are “different” applications..

Comment: @user2864740 that is true but I think that level of complexity is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Not really. Using a DB transaction “as shown” in the original question takes approximately the same level of line complexity - less so if using the DB-provider transaction support (instead of adding manual SQL statements), which should also handle non-local abort cases.

Comment: @Z4-tier each user is accessing the database in a separate thread. And database operations are simple. One read and one write. That is all.

Comment: @user2864740 the similarities and differences between what might be accomplished when comparing these constructs is going to depend on what `perform database operations` entails. In general though, unless you *know* that you need a mutex, it's likely a much safer bet to let the database handle locking.

Comment: @Z4-tier I’m in agreement ^_^

Comment: @KishanKumar In that case you might be able to get away with using the mutex, and it's possible that it could even be the superior option, but that starts to be really dependent on how the app is managing the database connections and threads. I'd still stick with the database transactions if it was my decision to make.